# CH340C vs ESP32 correct UART connection

Tags: esp32

I have problem knowing the right UARTs connection between CH340C and ESP32.

I have seen some connected RX<—>RX and TX<—>TX and it seems working. But after googling i found some went with crossed RX<—>TX and TX<—>RX it worked too. I used the later connection but CH340C is recognized but no serial detected. I probed 3.3V it’s okay, likely not power problem. What could be the issue?

Below are two  schematics illustrating the above scenarios;[image][image]

Comment: We cannot know until you provide schematics and how you wired things together. Anything could be an issue like a broken wire, until verified OK.

Comment: @Justme  I have added  images

Comment: Which one is your schematics? The other one is correct, the other one is incorrect. Are you sure about the correct CH340G vs CH340C version of the chip - The G model schematics are not correct either.

Comment: @Justme the first schematic is mine but the second one seems working. We  both soldered CH340C .